# Facebook API to get "watched" movies/TV show list or "read" book list?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

My facebook profile recently has been migrated to the new layout. In the about page, I found that movies/TV shows sections have been divided into 3 tabs "Watched", "Want to Watch", "Likes". Similar case applies to Books section.

I know that we can use "/me/movies" to get list of movies users liked. However, I can't find the way to get the list of "Watched" and "Want to Watch", which I found interesting to get.

Any suggestion about how I can access (read/write) to these lists in addition to already available "Likes" list for movies/TV show/books? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

video.watches
Returns no data as of April 4, 2018.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.watches/

If you use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and point to:
[https://graph.facebook.com/**me/video.watches**](https://graph.facebook.com/me?video_watches)

that will give you a list of videos watched.

If it does not, be sure that you have granted the **user_actions.video** permission by clicking the **Get Access Token** button, and then checking the user_actions.video box under **User Data Permissions**, and get a new access token.

My concern is also that there's seemingly no way to actually post to these collections programmatically via Graph. You can post a movie watched from your own app using the **video_watches** action, but it won't add it to the "Movies I've Watched" collection that the "Movies" application controls (an application seemingly only Facebook itself can post or update through). There's no way to get an access token to post AS the Movies application that I can see. Therefore, there's no way through Graph to post a "movie I've watched" or "movie I want to watch". It will just end up being sandboxed in your own application's collection.

If this is incorrect, please someone chime in on how this might be accomplished.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful info. Will dig deeper on this direction and share if I see anything interesting.

Comment: Works!! :) I am getting all watched movie. Thnx Bro!!

Comment: @NeerajSingh: Can you please tell how you got all watched movies?

Comment: @Karimkhan: just go on Facebook graph explorer tool, set permission for user 'user_actions.video' and submit with 'me?fields=video_watches'

Comment: ?fields=video_watches does not work, this results in an error:"message": "(#100) Unknown fields: video_watches.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100

it should be video.watches

Comment: I came across this error (#100) and you need to set parameters to null when using video.watches, I'm talking about how I solved in Android.

Comment: Is there any way to get the list of movies user have 1. Marked as watched, 2. Rated on Facebook via the SDK, after my app gets the required permissions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I input `me/video.watches` instead of `me?fields=video_watches`.

[Read this article for more information.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.watches/)